# Construction details for an HF Transceiver output power splitter

Tags: transmitter

I have a requirement to feed two HF power amplifiers with one HF radio transceiver, maximum input power is about 400 W, is it possible for someone to post an answer with schematic and construction details for such a device, or a link to something similar ?

Additionally, if i wanted to feed one antenna with the same two power amplifiers by using a similar power splitter but in reverse, is it ok to use amplifiers each with a different output power rating, say 700 W and 1000 W ?

And what happens if i turn off or remove one of the amplifiers ?

All of the input and output connections need to be 50 ohms.

Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Regarding your first scenario: What's the output power of the HF transceiver? How far is the transceiver from the PAs?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The output of the transceiver is 400 W and it is right next to the amplifiers so cables are less than 2 m in length.

Comment: Oh! I thought that the PAs' output was 400W, not their input! Wow! Ok in that case lossless splitting is kind of important.